# Exit roku app manually

Tags: exit, roku, brightscript

I need to exit from my roku app from one page ,when i press a specific button.

i was try ,

```
  MainMenuCanvas.Clear()
  MainMenuCanvas.Close()
```

But it does not exit from my app.I need to go to home screen by code.is it possible? The `MainMenuCanvas` is an inner page comes from some other pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exit the channel programmatically by issuing the End command...  I usually add the following function after my RunUserInterface function, so I can call it directly from anywhere in my code.

```
Sub ExitUserInterface()
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note this only works on the main thread. With Scene graph you can't call this on the UI thread to exit